# Unable to load DLL 'MyDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. asp.net p/invoke

Tags: asp.net, pinvoke

I am trying o p/invoke a c++ class i have created into a asp.net web application.
I have used the following tutorial - [p/invoke](http://manski.net/2012/05/29/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/)

I can get it working when creating a c# console applicatioin but not a web application

I get the following error when I run it -

"Unable to load DLL 'MyDll.dll': The specified module could not be found."

I have tried putting MyDll.dll into the bin folder but this does not work.

I have set the build path in my web application to match the MyDll.dll but i have read that
ASP.NET ignores this and automatically goes to the bin folder when you click debug(F5)

Answer (score 3):

Are you possibly running this on a machine where no C++ runtime is installed? The error message would be the one you wrote. Or there might also be another DLL missing. You can find this out using the DependencyWalker:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/